# Powerpoint VBA: Change language

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How does one create a macro which selects all words of a line and change the language to Dutch?

1. Not much experience with VBA, would not know where to start.
2. Keyboard definition is set to US, not Dutch, hence the US text control
3. Would not want to do several actions to set the check language to Dutch, for each part that needs to be turned to Dutch
4. Would prefer a key macro (f.e. Ctrl-D)

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow isn't the best place to start looking for programming language tutorials.  Google vba in PowerPoint for links to various "how-to" tutorials.

This will set the currently selected text to Dutch:

Activewindow.Selection.TextRange.LanguageID = msoLanguageIDDutch

Unfortunately, PPT doesn't support keyboard shortcuts to macros.